# ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in. with a custom component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to stick a custom-component into my current HTML and it is throwing the error above with the following detailed message:

```
 Example:

       
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });
```

Looking at the code, it does look like it wants to make sure that the control is initiated in the javascript before it is used in HTML. Below I smy html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" spellcheck="false" novalidate>
<app-dynamic-settings-form>
        formControlName="this.bclConvertFormValues">
      </app-dynamic-settings-form>
</form>
```

also, my component looks like the following:

```
private buildFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({

      bclConvertFormValues: new FormControl(''),

    });
  }
```

Should it not be sufficient to render control? Also, what I am wondering is if there is anything that I could be missing. Or how else could I debug it?